# Sequelize db seeding with async model query

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have 2 related tables, and i want seed on that tables. The users seeder is working fine, and
on my second seeder file I query all the users then attached every users on users_information table. Here is my code.

```
var chance = require('chance').Chance();
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    User.findAll()
      .then(users => {
        var usersInfo = [];
        for(let user of users) {
          var userInfo = {
            user_id: user.id,
            first_name: user.username,
            middle_name: chance.last(),
            last_name: chance.last(),
            address: chance.address()
          };
          usersInfo.push(userInfo);
        }

        return queryInterface.bulkInsert('users_information', usersInfo);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
      return queryInterface.bulkDelete('users_information', null, {});
  }
};
```

when i run db:seed:all command it runs without an error and the data on users_information table is empty.

The seeder is working without a model query. Just to test if my seeder file works.

```
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
     var usersInfo = [];

     for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       var userInfo = {
         user_id: i,
         first_name: chance.first(),
         middle_name: chance.last(),
         last_name: chance.last(),
         address: chance.address()
       };
       usersInfo.push(userInfo);
     }
     return queryInterface.bulkInsert('users_information', usersInfo);
},
```

here's my tables

**users table**

```
- id (PK)
- username
- user_type
- is_active
```

**users_information table**

```
- id (PK)
- user_id (FK)
- first_name
- last_name
- address
```

Any suggestions or idea? Thanks!

Comment: i also tried adding user = user.get({plain: true}); in the users loop, still not working

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem. Mine was resolved by returning a promise. *I think* sequelize is expecting a promise to be returned. It will wait until a promise is resolved or rejected. If a promise is not return I think it assumes everything is "done" and "good". Your first example is not returning a promise. it just "runs" and exists without waiting for all the async code to complete (aka User.findAll()).

**Solution:**
I think if you return a promise in your **up** method and resolve it when you are "done" I think that will work. Example:

```
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // return a new promise that sequelize will wait for...
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         User.findAll()
              .then(users => {
                var usersInfo = [];
                for(let user of users) {
                  var userInfo = {
                    user_id: user.id,
                    first_name: user.username,
                    middle_name: chance.last(),
                    last_name: chance.last(),
                    address: chance.address()
                  };
                  usersInfo.push(userInfo);
                }
                // Notice we are not returning this.
                queryInterface.bulkInsert('users_information', usersInfo);
                resolve('Done');
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                reject(error)
              });
    }
  },
```